# Working with each AND window.location on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have another question involving each loops. I have a view which displays a current classroom. It shows how many students are online atm, etc. Within a div located on the bottom right i have a table that lists all the available classrooms. The "name" of the classroom is a button which makes the page refresh with new parameters (:class_id) and then shows the "clicked" classroom.

My problem is identifying the proper ID for each row in the table within the each do loop.

I have this code in my view (Example)

```
<% @classrooms.each do |room| %>
<table>
  <tr>
     <td><%= room.id %></td>
     <td><button onclick= "class()"><%= room.class %></button></td>
  </tr>
</table>
<script>function class(){window.location = '<%= classroom_path(:class_id = room.id)%>'};</script>
<% end %>
```

Its redirecting with the new param, but the class_id is the same for all the entries (last one). Any help? This is probably fairly simple, not sure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm confused. Why not use a real link ?

```
<% @classrooms.each do |room| %>
  <%= link_to room.class, classroom_path(room) %>
<% end %>
```

If you don't want a link (which can be styled as a button with virtually any css framework; including bootstrap); you can always do :

```
<% @classrooms.each do |room| %>
  <%= button_to classroom_path(room), method: :get, value: room.class %>
<% end %>
```

if you want to do it via js / jquery, here you go:

```
<% @classrooms.each do |room| %>
  <%= tag :button, data: {url: classroom_path(room)}, class: 'js_button' ,value: room.class %>
<% end %>
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).on('click', '.js_button', function(){
    window.location = this.getAttribute("data-url");
  });
<script>
```

also, typo:  `classroom_path(:class_id = room.id)`

Comment: there's a slight delay before you can mark an answer as correct. Then, under this answer's score, you should see a checkmark that appears (maybe on hover), just click it. Maybe you need a minimum reputation to do that, id on't remember

Comment: Thanks for the new answers! :D

Comment: Yeah, i tried giving a vote but it says i need more reputation.. Judging how im making some questions with rather... obvious answers, i doubt im getting reputation anything soon :p But thanks for the help everyone!

Answer (score 0):

Your syntax looks wrong. Try

```
<td><%= room.id %></td>
```

And also `<%= room.class %>`

If you want to output data in erb, you need `<%=` not just <%`

Also, you are redefining the `class()` function for each `@classroom` object, so any button click would call the same function each time. You aren't making a new function for each instance.

But, this could all be cleaned up much easier by just doing a simple `link_to` and using path helpers like `<%= link_to room.class, class %>`

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out. I didnt copy-paste it, so i missed the = . Thanks again cpjolicoeur :)